# How to pull out sub-string from string (Android)?

Tags: java, android, string, substring

I'm trying to pull out sub-string from a string using `java.Util.Scan`

The sub-string is between "`<TD class=MoreB align=center>`"  and  "`</TD>`" in the original string

This is the code:

```
public static String pullStringOut(String str)
{
    String stringer = null;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str);
    scanner.findInLine("<TD class=MoreB align=center>");

    while (scanner.hasNext() && scanner.next() != "</TD>")
    {
        stringer+= " " + (scanner.next());
    }

    return stringer;
}
```

but it's not working well.

From the original string:

"`<TD class=MoreB align=center>TextTextTextText</TD></TR></TABLE> }`"

I get the following result:

> "`TextTextTextText</TD></TR></TABLE> }`"

Instead of the expected

> "TextTextTextText"

Comment: don't use scanner if possible, but use some DOM parsing utility. like `JSoup` or `TagSoup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Regex Expresssion.

Something like :

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/\<TD class=MoreB align=center>(.*)\<\/td\>/"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher(str); 
while(m.find()) { 

  //do whatever you want here
 }
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 1):

A few problems:

- `scanner.next() != "</TD>"` will always be `true` as the operands will not be the same object. Use `!scanner.next().equals("</TD>")`. From [Reference Equality Operators == and != section of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3):

  > The result of != is false if the operand values are both null or both refer to
  >   the same object or array; otherwise, the result is true.
- `scanner.next()` is being called twice on each iteration of the loop. Change to:

  ```
  String line;
  while (scanner.hasNext() && !(line = scanner.next()).equals("</TD>"))
  {
      stringer+= " " + line;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution:

```
String tvt ="<TD class=MoreB align=center>TextTextTextText</TD></TR></TABLE> }" //your original string
                String s ="<TD class=MoreB align=center>";
                String f= "</TD>";
                int sindex =tvt.indexOf(s);
                int findex =tvt.indexOf(f);
                String fs = "";
                if(sindex!=-1 && findex!=-1)
                fs=tvt.substring(sindex+s.length(), findex); // your desired substring
```